# Tag Values for Images in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, image, enterprise-architect

I am working on Enterprise Architect C# add-ins. I am unable to find a tag value for adding images as value. I had tried for creating Tagged value Type=File as shown below:

```
EA.TaggedValue fileTag=ele.TaggedValues.AddNew("Image_Tag", "File");
fileTag.Value = "@D:\\img11.bmp";
fileTag.Update();
ele.Update();
```

I add image to tagged value file manually created as shown below. On clicking Launch option, I was able to view the image as well.

[image: file tagged value]
It only creates a tagged value of Type=String. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What? Since when can an image be placed in a tag? Please show how you create it manually.

Comment: I have edited the answer with the same. Please check it.

Comment: What's your EA version?

Comment: its version 13.0

Answer (score 2):

The type parameter doesn't work here.

You just have to define the tagged value in the model and create it using its name.

EA will then recognize the name and set the type according to the definition.

Tagged value definition can be created directly in the model or be imported via an MDG technology file.

To create it directly in the model you can use something like this:

```
    public void addTaggedValueType(string tagName, string tagDescription, string tagDetail)
    {
        global::EA.PropertyType taggedValueType = (global::EA.PropertyType)myEARepository.PropertyTypes.AddNew(tagName, "");
        taggedValueType.Description = tagDescription;
        taggedValueType.Detail = tagDetail;
        taggedValueType.Update();
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
const string elementTagDetail = @"Type=RefGUID;
Values=Class;DataType;Enumeration;PrimitiveType;
AppliesTo=Class;DataType;Enumeration;PrimitiveType;"; 

this.EAModel.addTaggedValueType(this.settings.elementTagName, "is derived from this Element", elementTagDetail);
```

Comment: Thank you..I created a Type=File tagged value and it got added to the model and I am able to see it in UML Types ->Tagged Value Types window as well. I need to add this File tagged value to the new element that I am creating. I am unable to use element.Taggedvalues.AddNew() since the tagged value is already exists.